# Learning from urn draws when the urn can be replaced

Tags: probability, bayesian, stochastic-processes

Suppose there is an urn consisting of black and white balls. This urn is filled with a proportion $a$ of black balls, where $a\sim U[0,1]$.

Balls are consecutively drawn from that urn (with replacement). After observing $n$ draws, out of which $k$ show a black ball, the estimated proportion of black balls in the urn is equal to

$$\frac{k + 1}{n+2}.$$

As $n$ increases, we'd expect this estimate to be further away from the prior expectation about the proportion of black balls (which is $1/2$) on average. This reflects that the estimate becomes more precise as more draws are observed.

Now consider the same process but let there be a probability $b>0$ that the urn is replaced by a new urn between any two draws. If the urn is replaced, the proportion of black balls in the new urn is again randomly drawn from the uniform distribution. I'm interested in whether we can say anything about how $b$ affects how much we can learn about the proportion of black balls in the current urn (i.e., the urn from which the most recent draw was made).

For example, suppose that $n$ becomes very large. If $b=0$, the estimate of $a$ will always be very precise as the proportion of black balls drawn converges to the true proportion of black balls. However, if $b=1$, then we can only rely on the most recent draw to estimate the proportion of black balls. That is, the estimate is either equal to $\frac{1}{3}$ or $\frac{2}{3}$, which is imprecise. I wonder if it is true in general that the estimate becomes less precise as $b$ increases.

What I've found so far is that the expectation about $a$ can be written as a weighted average of the expectation of $a$ conditional on the urn having last been exchanged $m$ draws ago, where $m$ is equal to $1,...,n$. As $b$ increases, there is more weight being put on the event that the urn has been exchanged fewer rather than more draws ago. At this point I am a bit stuck, even though it seems like the result should follow from the fact that the estimate of $a$ relies on fewer urn draws as $b$ increases.